# Close button doesn't work after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

Okay so I got JQuery and after clicking filter icon whole < body > moves to the right,filter icon vanishes and filter list comes up,and with it close button shows up. Close button has position:fixed but problem is that after scrolling down button doesn't work anymore,and when i scroll to the top of the page it works.Here is CSS to that button.

`#close{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    position:fixed;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-left:210px;
    }`

https://plnkr.co/edit/TbOf9hkPILJn2snW8D7A
See it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add z-index property to your css. The close button does not work any more because it is behind the other elements.

Try to change your style.css so that the #close style is:

```
#close{
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   position:fixed;
   color:black;
   cursor:pointer;
   margin-left:160px;

   z-index: 100;
```

}